# Maven build optimization - prevent building *-fat.jar locally

Tags: java, maven

Right now I see this in my project:

[image]

I have a pretty optimized maven build using:

```
mvn -offline -T 9 package exec:java -DskipTests
```

the offline flag prevents it from looking for updates, uses 9 threads, and skips tests, but I wonder if there is a flag I can use to prevent it from creating the `*-fat.jar`?

I figure the fat.jar is a big file and if I avoid creating it until I need to, might save some time.

Comment: Which Maven plugin do you use to create the `-fat.jar`?

Comment: i am not sure what plugin it is, but the fat.jar is what I use when I deploy as a single file, i figure it's a popular format?

Comment: @JFMeier It is apparently part of the vert.x default pom.

Answer (score 2):

Maven is not creating something like "-fat.jar" by default. It mast be specific definition in the pom.xml: maven-assembly-plugin or maven-shade-plugin which do it.

So, you need to change your pom.xml: define special profiles: one(defualt) which will create "-fat.jar" and one which will not.

And then you will able to run something like "mav package -Pmy-no-fat-profile" to avoid "-fat.jar" creation.

Comment: thanks, do you have the exact command line flag that I can use? I would like to keep my pom.xml configuration, and just use a command line switch to prevent fat.jar from being created.

Comment: There is no such flag. 
And you can't reach your goal without changes in your pom.xml. 
You need to modify it by adding special profile.